# Impossible CPU core/threads configuration

Tags: slurm

I am trying to set up a test instance of slurmd and seemingly cannot get it to accept my CPU.

Here's the output of lscpu:

```
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  24
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-23
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
  Model name:            12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12900K
    CPU family:          6
    Model:               151
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  16
    Socket(s):           1
    Stepping:            2
    CPU max MHz:         6700.0000
    CPU min MHz:         800.0000
    BogoMIPS:            6374.40
    Flags:               ...
```

Now the obvious choice of config IMHO would be:

```
Sockets=1 CoresPerSocket=16 ThreadsPerCore=2
```

but

```
slurmd: error: Thread count (24) not multiple of core count (16)
```

Also setting CPUs=16 doesn't work either

```
slurmd: error: Thread count (24) not multiple of core count (16)
slurmd: error: Node configuration differs from hardware: CPUs=16:24(hw) Boards=1:1(hw) SocketsPerBoard=1:1(hw) CoresPerSocket=16:16(hw) ThreadsPerCore=2:1(hw)
```

Setting `ThreadsPerCore=1` doesn't change anything.

I think I did try every possible combination of settings and it always fails due to a mismatch of detected numbers or expected multiplication results.

So,

1. How do I make slurm believe me that my CPU actually exists and preferably even start?
2. Why do these config settings exist at all when the daemon seemingly only trust its own hardware detection? Do they have an effect?

Comment: The i9-12900K ist a 16 Core CPU indeed, but only 8 of the cores support Hyperthreading leading to 16+8 = 24 threads. Until there is an update that supports your CPU, you could deactivate the E Cores and habe a 8 Core, 16 Thread Machine.

Comment: Gonna give that a try, yes

Comment: I guess 1.5 as ThreadsPerCore won’t work and not setting these parameters, you’ve surely tried already.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make slurm believe me that my CPU actually exists and preferably even start?

You can set `CPUs=24` in the node definition line and set the [config_overrides](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html#OPT_config_overrides) parameter.

From the man page: "If set, consider the configuration of each node to be that specified in the slurm.conf configuration file"

> Why do these config settings exist at all when the daemon seemingly only trust its own hardware detection? Do they have an effect?

I think this act as a sanity check on one hand, and on the other hand, it allows the slurm controller to know in advance the node configuration, which is needed to build its internal data structures upon startup.

Comment: That unfortunately does not work. Still refuses to accept the config.

Comment: did you remove `Sockets=1 CoresPerSocket=16 ThreadsPerCore=2` ?